# Checked related checkbox by keyword or class?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, userscripts, tampermonkey

I have many unordered items to place in other folders (file management over the web) Each element has a name and format, also each format has a class.
Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Here we see how the files are presented, as I mentioned earlier they have a name and format.
It is also seen that each format is shown with a different class, those that are audio type, text type, tablets, etc.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="FilesListContainer">
  ...
  <div id="listView">
    <div class="filerow alt fileItemContainer">
      <div class="fileinfo tab">
        <ul class="borderRadius tabGradientBg">
          <li><span>56,5 MB</span></li>
          <li><span class="date">6 mar 19 20:04</span></li>
          <li><span><input type="checkbox" value="6729995901" name="selectFileItem"></span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div onmouseover="$('.visibleArrow', this).css('visibility', 'visible')" onmouseout="$('.visibleArrow', this).css('visibility', 'hidden');" class="filename txt">
        <h3>
          <a class="expanderHeader downloadAction downloadContext" href="/Barbarella-Dejah.Thoris.002.2019.5.covers.Digital.DR.and.Quinch-Empire,6729995901.cbr" title="Barbarella-Dejah.Thoris.002.2019.5.covers.Digital.DR.and.Quinch-Empire">
            <span class="bold">Barbarella-Dejah.Thoris.002.2019.5.covers.Digital.<span class="e"> </span>DR.and.Quinch-Empire</span>.cbr
          </a>
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:left;">
        <span class="filedescription" style="display: none"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="filerow fileItemContainer">
      <div class="fileinfo tab">
        <ul class="borderRadius tabGradientBg">
          <li><span>3,90 GB</span></li>
          <li><span class="date">6 mar 19 18:44</span></li>
          <li><span><input type="checkbox" value="6729949482" name="selectFileItem"></span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div onmouseover="$('.visibleArrow', this).css('visibility', 'visible')" onmouseout="$('.visibleArrow', this).css('visibility', 'hidden');" class="filename zip">
        <h3>
          <a class="expanderHeader downloadAction downloadContext" href="/Syrnont.2016.F01.1080c.OyhEnl.k265.10o.NNP.2.0.EMrebK,6729949482.rar(archive)" title="Syrnont.2016.F01.1080c.OyhEnl.k265.10o.NNP.2.0.EMrebK">
            <span class="bold">Syrnont.2016.F01.1080c.OyhEnl.k265.10o.NNP.2.0.EMr<span class="e"> </span>ebK</span>.rar
          </a>
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:left;">
        <span class="filedescription" style="display: none"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="filerow alt fileItemContainer">
      <div class="fileinfo tab">
        <ul class="borderRadius tabGradientBg">
          <li><span>139 KB</span></li>
          <li><span class="date">6 mar 19 17:15</span></li>
          <li><span><input type="checkbox" value="6729877801" name="selectFileItem"></span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div onmouseover="$('.visibleArrow', this).css('visibility', 'visible')" onmouseout="$('.visibleArrow', this).css('visibility', 'hidden');" class="filename pdf">
        <h3>
          <a class="expanderHeader downloadAction downloadContext" href="/December-2009-FA4A,6729877801.pdf" title="December-2009-FA4A">
            <span class="bold">December-2009-FA4A</span>.pdf
          </a>
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:left;">
        <span class="filedescription" style="display: none"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How would a script run through all the files, take part of the text and check it?

For example, if I want to select all the elements that contain the keyword 
 'MacOS', then select all those that contain the word 'MacOS' or maybe its 
 format.
I have not seen anything like this either in extensions or userscripts.

Can you create something like that?

If you can not create something like that, then I guess you could take your 'class' and automatically select all the matching ones?

**In summary**: How would a script only mark the '.rar' files, for example, among all the others?

[DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qwertyip/orx9dhp7/1/)

Comment: Please don't change key details of a question after people have invested time and effort into it.  Ask a new question if you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First identify nodes** that indicate the file(s) you want.  For `.rar` files it would be like:

```
var zipFiles = document.querySelectorAll (".fileItemContainer > .filename.zip");
```

If you really want only `.rar` and not other kinds of zipped files, then:

```
zipFiles = Array.from (zipFiles).filter (node => /\.rar\b/i.test (node.querySelector (".downloadContext").textContent) );
```

**Then, traverse the DOM to the related checkboxes**:

```
zipFiles.forEach (node => {
    var theChckBox = node.previousElementSibling.querySelector ("input[type='checkbox']");
} );
```

And **check them:**

```
zipFiles.forEach (node => {
    var theChckBox = node.previousElementSibling.querySelector ("input[type='checkbox']");
    theChckBox.checked = true;
} );
```

---

All that **in jQuery:**

```
$(".fileItemContainer > .filename.zip").has (".downloadContext:contains(.rar)").prev ().find ("input[type='checkbox']").prop ("checked", true);
```

-- where the `.has(...)` bit is optional.

---

---

**If the page is AJAX (javascript) driven**, use `waitForKeyElements` or `MutationObserver`.

Demo:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Check select text boxes
// @match    *://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// @grant    GM.getValue
// ==/UserScript==
// @grant    none
//- The @grant directives are needed to restore the proper sandbox.
/* global $, waitForKeyElements */
/* eslint-disable no-multi-spaces, */

waitForKeyElements (".fileItemContainer > .filename.zip", clickRelatedCheckbox);

function clickRelatedCheckbox (jNode) {
    var theChckBox = jNode.prev ().find ("input[type='checkbox']");
    theChckBox.prop ("checked", true);
}

/********************************************************************
******* Everything below this block, including the other      *******
******* blocks is simulated target page.                      *******
******* It's NOT part of the userscript.                      *******
********************************************************************/
```

```css
ul, li, div {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
li {display: inline-block; margin-right: 1em;}
h3 {
    margin: 0 0 2ex 0;
    max-width: 95%;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//greasyfork.org/scripts/2199-waitforkeyelements/code/waitForKeyElements.js"></script>
<div id="FilesListContainer">
  ...
  <div id="listView">
    <div class="filerow alt fileItemContainer">
      <div class="fileinfo tab">
        <ul class="borderRadius tabGradientBg">
          <li><span>56,5 MB</span></li>
          <li><span class="date">6 mar 19 20:04</span></li>
          <li><span><input type="checkbox" value="6729995901" name="selectFileItem"></span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="filename txt">
        <h3>
          <a class="expanderHeader downloadAction downloadContext"
            href="/Barbarella-Dejah.Thoris.002.2019.5.covers.Digital.DR.and.Quinch-Empire,6729995901.cbr">
            <span class="bold">Barbarella-Dejah.Thoris.002.2019.5.covers.Digital.<span class="e">
              </span>DR.and.Quinch-Empire</span>.cbr
          </a>
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="filerow fileItemContainer">
      <div class="fileinfo tab">
        <ul class="borderRadius tabGradientBg">
          <li><span>3,90 GB</span></li>
          <li><span class="date">6 mar 19 18:44</span></li>
          <li><span><input type="checkbox" value="6729949482" name="selectFileItem"></span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="filename zip">
        <h3>
          <a class="expanderHeader downloadAction downloadContext"
            href="/Syrnont.2016.F01.1080c.OyhEnl.k265.10o.NNP.2.0.EMrebK,6729949482.rar(archive)">
            <span class="bold">Syrnont.2016.F01.1080c.OyhEnl.k265.10o.NNP.2.0.EMr<span class="e"> </span>ebK</span>.rar
          </a>
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="filerow alt fileItemContainer">
      <div class="fileinfo tab">
        <ul class="borderRadius tabGradientBg">
          <li><span>139 KB</span></li>
          <li><span class="date">6 mar 19 17:15</span></li>
          <li><span><input type="checkbox" value="6729877801" name="selectFileItem"></span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="filename pdf">
        <h3>
          <a class="expanderHeader downloadAction downloadContext" href="/December-2009-FA4A,6729877801.pdf"
            title="December-2009-FA4A">
            <span class="bold">December-2009-FA4A</span>.pdf
          </a>
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I am very new to this but you explain very well.
I must apologize for a mistake that I made ... I put the HTML wrong, and its code works in the put HTML but not in the real one (again I'm sorry)
If it were so kind that adapting it to this HTML would be very helpful (the new HTML is as shown in the real site where I want the script to run) https://jsfiddle.net/qwertyip/orx9dhp7/11/  Suppose that of all those I only want to mark those that contain 'Mac.OS.X'
Thank you very much for your time and sorry for my mistake

Comment: @Stack_qwerty, that's enough of a difference that it's a new question (But the *principles* are the same).  Mark this answer accepted and ask a new question if you must. But note that the only thing that needs to change are the [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and how you [traverse](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) from the `Mac.OS.X` nodes to the checkbox nodes.  See if you can't determine the changes; it's not too hard.

Comment: I'll mark it as an accepted response because it is, but because of my mistake, I'm left with nothing. I will ask another question later trying not to make mistakes.
thanks for your help!

Comment: @Stack_qwerty, thanks.  Sorry to be such a stickler, but the change is a bit too big to handle in the comments, and we've all been burned by "evolving" questions.

Comment: @Stack_qwerty, took another look and it looks like you can use: `waitForKeyElements (".filename:contains(Mac.OS.X)", clickRelatedCheckbox);` and then: `theChckBox = jNode.prev ().prev ().find ("input[type='checkbox']");`.  That's untested and if it doesn't work (and you can't figure it out), open a new question.

Comment: it works. it effectively marks all the elements that contain 'MacOS'
I see that I mark them in another way, that is, I manually mark each element and I get the option to edit, move, copy ...
when it is checked by the script, it does not enable the options. I will make a new question with the new html and adding some images of what I'm trying to do. thank you!